# dplyr assign value to column based on multiple filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains the following columns: `city`, `amenity`, `date` and I want to add a column `last` based on grouping together `city` and `amenity`, then taking the most recent date.

input dataframe:

```
| city      | amenity       | date                |
|-----------|---------------|---------------------|
| rome      | stadium       | 2020-02-25 19:10:40 | 
| new york  | concert hall  | 2020-03-09 18:15:29 |
| rome      | stadium       | 2020-02-29 15:07:23 |
| stockholm | swimming pool | 2020-03-02 11:23:54 |
| new york  | skate park    | 2020-03-12 13:41:35 |
| stockholm | swimming pool | 2020-03-13 17:54:23 |
| stockholm | swimming pool | 2020-03-18 19:18:29 |
```

desired output:

```
| city      | amenity       | date                | last |
|-----------|---------------|---------------------|------|
| rome      | stadium       | 2020-02-25 19:10:40 |      |
| new york  | concert hall  | 2020-03-09 18:15:29 | TRUE |
| rome      | stadium       | 2020-02-29 15:07:23 | TRUE |
| stockholm | swimming pool | 2020-03-02 11:23:54 |      |
| new york  | skate park    | 2020-03-12 13:41:35 | TRUE |
| stockholm | swimming pool | 2020-03-13 17:54:23 |      |
| stockholm | swimming pool | 2020-03-18 19:18:29 | TRUE |
```

---

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(city = c("rome", "newyork", "rome", "stockholm", 
"newyork", "stockholm", "stockholm"), amenity = c("stadium", 
"concert_hall", "stadium", "swimming_pool", "skate_park", "swimming_pool", 
"swimming_pool"), date = structure(c(1582632640, 1583752529, 
1582963643, 1583123034, 1583995295, 1584096863, 1584533909), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested since the data cannot easily be copied into R, but something like this.

```
data %>%
  group_by(city, amenity) %>%
  mutate(last = (date == max(date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is sorted by `date`, `df$last = !duplicated(df[, c("city", "amenity")], fromLast = TRUE)`. That will put `FALSE` instead of missing values, but should work.

Comment: Thanks, although you missed to close your sqaure bracket: `df$last = !duplicated(df[, c("city", "amenity")], fromLast = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, fixed in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(city, amenity) %>% 
  mutate(
    last = if_else(date == max(date), TRUE, NA)
  )
```

I've set `NA` instead of `FALSE` since in your desired output there is no value in the non-last dates.

---

Output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   city, amenity [4]
  city      amenity       date                last 
  <chr>     <chr>         <dttm>              <lgl>
1 rome      stadium       2020-02-25 13:10:40 NA   
2 newyork   concert_hall  2020-03-09 12:15:29 TRUE 
3 rome      stadium       2020-02-29 09:07:23 TRUE 
4 stockholm swimming_pool 2020-03-02 05:23:54 NA   
5 newyork   skate_park    2020-03-12 07:41:35 TRUE 
6 stockholm swimming_pool 2020-03-13 11:54:23 NA   
7 stockholm swimming_pool 2020-03-18 13:18:29 TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, however it seems to me that is not taking into account the time but only the date. Am I correct?

Comment: @sanna. The date variable has class "POSIXct", which includes date and time.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this.

Comment: Thanks Edward for answering for me :D     @sanna It works with class POSIXct as yours, I insert in the answer the output I obtain